# JavaScript saving document.write in a variable and calling it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass `document.write` as a reference to a variable:

Example:

```
var f = document.write

//then
f('test');
```

It works with alert. Why doesn't it work with `document.write`?

Comment: It may not work because the `write` function expects to be executed on the context of a `document` and not the `window`.

Comment: You could `.bind()` it, but you'd need a shim for older browsers, and I don't know how it would impact performance. `var f = document.write.bind(document);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to what's already said, Javascript 1.8.5 has a native solution for the problem : the [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
f = document.write.bind(document)
f("hello")
```

The link above also contains emulation code for browsers that don't support JS 1.8.5 yet.

Answer (score 10):

Because `alert` doesn't care what `this` is (`alert` is a global) and `document.write` does (it needs to know which document it is writing to).

If you want a wrapper, then write a shortcut function.

```
function f(str) { document.write(str); }
```

… and then go and ritually disembowel yourself for calling the variable `f`. [Self-describing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting) is a virtue of good code.

Comment: Exactly, you would have to call `f` like this: `f.apply(document, [str])` ... somewhat defeating the purpose I suppose? At least you can still create a shortened reference to the `document` object.

Answer (score 4):

Some functions, including `eval` and `document.write` cannot be used indirectly (ie, by referencing through variables).

If you still want to use `document.write` using `f`, use:

```
function f(s){
    document.write(s);
}
f('test');
```

Comment: @Dennis `document.write` seems to loose its context when the function is indirectly referred. When using the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method, it's possible to indirectly refer to `document.write`. Code: `var f=document.write; f.call(document, 'test')`

Comment: If you want to reference it by variable, you have to reference a function IE: `var f = function(i) { document.write(i); }`

Comment: With respect to `eval`, are you talking about specific browser issues? ES-5 describes the required behavior for indirect calls to `eval`, and references the behavior of indirect calls under ES-3.

Comment: ...ah, I see there must have been specific implementation issues: *"Implementations are no longer permitted to restrict the use of eval in ways that are not a direct call."*

Answer (score 3):

Why it doesn't work I can't say without more research, but to solve your problem:

```
var f = function(i) { document.write(i); }
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's because you're not applying f to the document (but to the window)

This works:

```
var f = document.write;
f.call(document, "Hello world!!!");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it looses the correct value of `this` inside the `write` function...

You can pass a reference to `document`...

```
var f = document;

f.write("hello");
```

Or wrap it like other solutions suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Another, strange way to do this, is:

```
var f = window.document.write;
f.call(window.document, "test")
```

Or:

```
var f = document.write;
f.apply(document, ["test"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue as posted in this question: [Javascript Class Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001478/javascript-class-inheritance)

As others have mentioned you're loosing the functions context. Functions are objects like anything else in javascript. by calling `var f = document.write` you are getting a reference to the function, but the function does not have the reference to the document that it needs.

example:

```
// give the window a new funciton
window.foo = function () {
    console.log('FOO!);
}

// get a reference to this funciton
var fn = window.foo;

// call via reference works and outputs 'FOO!!' to the console
fn();

// attach it to your object
var myObject = {};
myObject.Foo = fn;

// call it it still works
myObject.Foo();
```

now if the function references `this` then the above *does not work* because `this` dependes on the calling context. The way to save the context at the moment is to use a closure like this...

```
// remember this is the window context

var fn = function (s) { 
    document.write(s);
}
```

The reason the above code works is javascript looks at the function and doesn't see a local `document` object so it walks up the scope and sees the outer scope (in this case the `window` object) has a document and calls write on that. Effectively the call to `document.write()` is the same as writing `window.document.write()`