# Javascript Class Inheritance

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why my 'showDiv_boo' is undefined inside the class´s method?
I also can´t access my class´s methods.

Here´s my class 'Blink' class with its properties and methods:

```
function Blink(div) {
    this.div = div
}
Blink.prototype.counter = 0
Blink.prototype.showDiv_boo = true
Blink.prototype.showDiv = function() {
    this.div.style.visibility = 'visible'
}
Blink.prototype.hideDiv = function() {
    this.div.style.visibility = 'hidden'
}
Blink.prototype.startEngine = function() {
    if (this.showDiv_boo) {
        this.showDiv()
    } else if (!this.showDiv_boo) {
        this.hideDiv()
    }
    this.showDiv_boo = !this.showDiv_boo
    this.counter++
}
Blink.prototype.startEffect = function() {
    this.idEffect = setInterval(this.startEngine, 1000 / 45)
}
```

So, if I create:

```
_blink = new Blink(myDiv);
_blink.startEffect();
```

You can test... the variable 'showDiv_boo', is undefined inside the method.

Even, if I set the showDiv_boo inside the method to true, it won´t call my class´s methods showDiv or hideDiv.

Anyone?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. use `var self` and call the method via `self.startEngine()`
2. use an anonymous function to wrap the call in [1] i.e. `function(){ self.startEngine(); }`

This is because when you just pass `this.startEngine` or `self.startEngine` you are just passing the function startEngine without specifying what `this` is, which in both cases is supplied by the global conext of `DOMWindow`.

To give an example...

```
function startEngine() { 
  ...code omitted... 
};

Blink.prototype.startEngine = startEngine;

Blink.prototype.start = function() {
  setTimeout(startEngine, 0);       // obviously wrong, what is this?
  setTimeout(Blink.startEngine, 0); // actually the same as line above, although not as obvious
  setTimeout(startEngine.bind(this), 0); // works correctly
}
```

works to add code to the prototype and if used in the anonymous function will work as expected, but if you just use `Blink.startEngine` as the callback it is exactly the same as using `startEngine` only the second is more obviously wrong because there's no object it is being called on so you'd expect `this` to be whatever is supplied by the context.

The other way you could do this without using the anonymous function would be

```
  Blink.startEngine.bind(self)
```

Which returns a function that will call `startEngine` with the correct `this` same as explicitly creating the anonymous function and wrapping the call to `self.startEngine()`

Heres a link to a fiddle to play around with the differences: http://jsfiddle.net/bonza_labs/MdeTF/

Answer (score 5):

The reason why is that `startEngine` is called from `setInterval`.  The way in which this callback is invoked causes `startEngine` to have a different value for `this` than `startEffect`.  You need to save `this` in order to maintain it in the callback.  For example.

```
Blink.prototype.startEffect = function () { 
  var self = this;
  self.idEffect = setInterval(function () { self.startEngine(); }, 1000 / 45);
};
```

Comment: Hi.
I´ve tried to use 'var self' and same thing.
showDiv_boo is undefined inside startEngine method.

Comment: Think you may not be wrapping it in the anonymous function -- doing both is key. If you don't use the anonymous function `self.startEngine` and `this.startEngine` are exactly the same. See my answer for further explaination.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following, you will find it is defined

```
var x = new Blink('hello');
x.showDiv_boo
```

Javascript uses prototypical inheritance. While showDiv_boo may not be explicitly defined within the instance of Blink that you now have, it does exist within the prototype that Blink inherits from. When you try referencing showDiv_boo from within the object, the Javascript engine realizes the object does not own a member by that name and then will check its prototype.

Comment: How can I access 'showDiv_boo' inside 'startEngine' method?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Along with setting a temporal variable to store `this`, you must call the `startEngine()` function with that variable:

```
Blink.prototype.startEffect = function(){
   var self = this;
   self.idEffect = setInterval(function(){ self.startEngine.call(self); }, 1000/45);
}
```

Note the `.call(self)`, which basically calls the function with the variable `self`, so the variable `this` in `startEngine` will be the correct one.

Comment: Just calling `self.startEngine()` is sufficient you don't need to also explicitly bind the call to self again.